# Undefined symbols on Runtime that cause no Error on Compile/Link Time

Tags: linux, gcc, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I have been searching for this a bit on Google, and there are also some topics on StackOverFlow but they don't answer the main question: Why sometimes, under GCC on LINUX (and I mean Linux since on MinGW it doesn't happen with the SAME code), an application compiles and links correctly with other libraries, without any errors and then, on execution time, undefined symbols are thrown?

Why wasn't this undefined symbol thrown during compilation/linking time?

What is the reason for the linker to accept the libraries and the code even though that such function has not been defined? Why only during execution time this problem is detected?

EDIT:

What it happens is for example, I have, on a header file of Class A the method play() but then i never implemented A::play(). When calling this function from another project file, which Links to the initial library where Class A is defined doesn't give me any undefined symbol error, when it should, since A::play() is not implemented. Later on, on Execution time, the application crashes on explicit load of Libraries, and I get the error string saying "undefined symbol play", for example. Quite strange...

Comment: Can you give the precise error messages you're getting?

Comment: sounds like your linker used a dynamic library that your OS doesn't have.  Error messages and your link command might also be useful.

Comment: You mean excluding dlopen?

Comment: All these libraries are MY OWN compiled libraries.

Comment: What it happens is for example, I have, on a header file of Class A the method play() but then i never implemented A::play().

When calling this function from another project file, which Links to the initial library where Class A is defined doesn't give me any undefined symbol error, when it should, since A::play() is not implemented. Later on, on Execution time, the application crashes on explicit load of Libraries, and I get the error string saying "undefined symbol play", for example. Quite strange...